# Comprobación de cadena vacía en Shell Script

Tags: shell, shell-script

El comando test -z es verdadero si la cadena está vacío.
El comando test -n es verdadero si la cadena NO está vacía

Tengo el siguiente script:

```
#!/bin/bash
cad1="HOLA"
cad2=""
test -z $cad2
echo "Expected 0, value is $?"
test -n $cad2
echo "Expected 1, value is $?"
```

Salida:

```
Expected 0, value is 0.
Expected 1, value is 0.
```

¿Por qué ambos salen como verdaderos? Si la cadena está vacía, no puede ser que salga verdadero que está vacía y que no lo está al mismo tiempo. ¿Qué se me está pasando por alto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La variable cad2 se expande sin comillas, lo que significa que si está vacía, se interpreta como si no se proporcionara ningún argumento a la prueba -z. Esto causa que test se ejecute de la siguiente manera:

```bash
test -z
```

Cuando test se ejecuta sin argumentos, siempre devuelve falso (valor 1), independientemente de lo que se esté probando. Por lo tanto, el resultado esperado es 0, pero el valor real es 1.

En el siguiente fragmento del código:

```bash
test -n $cad2
echo "Expected 1, value is $?"
```

Ocurre algo similar. La variable cad2 se expande sin comillas, lo que significa que si está vacía, se interpreta como si no se proporcionara ningún argumento a la prueba -n. Esto causa que test se ejecute de la siguiente manera:

```bash
test -n
```

Cuando test se ejecuta sin argumentos, nuevamente devuelve falso (valor 1). Por lo tanto, el resultado esperado es 1, pero el valor real es 1 nuevamente.

Para evitar este problema, es recomendable usar comillas alrededor de las variables en las pruebas de cadenas para asegurar que se manejen correctamente incluso cuando están vacías. Aquí está el código corregido:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
cad1="HOLA"
cad2=""
test -z "$cad2"
echo "Expected 0, value is $?"

test -n "$cad2"
echo "Expected 1, value is $?"
```

Visita: [ITM Developers](https://www.facebook.com/ITMDevelopers)

Comment: Muchas gracias! Bien explicado, no conocía esa característica de las variables vacías.